# JQuery .click() not firing when in col-sm or col-xs

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

My JQuery `.click()` code is working fine in .col-md but not firing when screen size is changed to col-sm or col-xs. The col-sm or col-xs `<div>` is hidden by `hidden-lg` and `hidden-md`. It looks like this

```
<div class="hidden-lg hidden-md col-xs-6 col-sm-6">
 <img class="test" /> 
</div>
<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-6 hidden-xs hidden-sm">
 <img class="test" /> 
</div>
```

The `$('.test').click(function(){...})` is working when in lg or md mode but not in xs or sm mode. Please advise?

My actual code:

```
<!--hidden when normal screen-->
<div id="hidden-arrows" class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
<div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
<span id="back-text" style="z-index:9999999;">Back</span><span>Next</span>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#back-text').click(function(){
   alert();
 });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Can't reproduce that problem, seems to work well in my end. One side note, is hidden-lg and hidden-md custom classes? At least on my fresh install of Bootstrap they're not doing anything, at least nothing that the names indicate.

Answer (score 0):

The image needs some specific width and height, otherwise it doesn't have space to click for triggering the click event. You can use style attribute to give height and width or give `alt` attribute with image specific text on it.

```
<img  style="width: 100px; height: 100px" class="test" />
<!-- OR -->
<img class="test" alt="Click me" />
```

Comment: @phpSiao Can you please share your test case like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/huj9wmm9/) here? This test is working fine.

Comment: I had amended for your perusal